# Wordpress along side Node using Nginx and Apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx

I'm trying to host a wordpress on /blog. I use Nginx as proxy and Apache to run Wordpress. I think I'm very close to a working solution.

The only problem I'm facing now is going to /blog/wp-admin loads the wordpress dashboard but then something is rewriting or redirecting to /wp-admin. The frontend pages are ok, e.g.: /blog/2015/05/28/hello-world/.

How can I figure out who is rewriting the dashboard url from **www.example.com/blog/wp-admin** into **www.example.com/wp-admin/** ?

This is my Nginx config:

```
upstream app_node {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

upstream app_wordpress {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name example.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/node.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/node.error.log debug;
  #port_in_redirect off;
  rewrite_log on;

  client_max_body_size 50M;

# pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers
location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

  proxy_pass http://app_node/;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
location ~ ^\/blog(.*)$ {

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080$1;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
       ServerName example.com:8080

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
</VirtualHost>
```

Wordpress htaccess (wordpress files are in /var/www/html):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It's probably wordpress not understanding it's rooted at `/blog` so it returns a link at `/`. Why are you using Apache *and* nginx here? Apache alone is quite capable of putting the root of your wp installation at `/blog` and doing the proxy to your node app.

Comment: I discovered that there is some javascript rewriting the window location <link id="wp-admin-canonical" rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/wp-admin/" />. This is from wp-admin/includes/misc.php. If i remove this it's working but I see that jquery doesn't load. I wanted nginx from the begining and now I use apache behind nginx because it works good with wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way but changed things a little bit.

Step 1.

Moved wordpress into /var/www/html/blog as described [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

Step 2.

- Nginx config unchanged
- Apache config unchanged

.htaccess generated by wordpress:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

Step 3.

Wordpress > Settings > General

- Wordpress Address (URL): http://example.com:8080/blog
- Site Address (URL): http://example.com/blog